# Permanently override background colour of Emacs theme

Tags: emacs, color-theme

I want to use the Emacs theme **billw**, except with a different background colour.
I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-billw)
(set-background-color "gray12")
```

However this doesn't seem to change the background colour on startup; I need to manually run `set-background-color "gray12"` in the minibuffer at the beginning of each session.

Any help with this? I tried creating my own custom theme based on the output of `color-theme-print` but this caused more problems than it's worth...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `color-theme-billw` function internally uses the `color-theme-install-frame-params` function to change frame parameters. So you can change frame parameters in the same way as follows:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-billw)
(color-theme-install-frame-params
  '((background-color . "gray12")))
```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>`color-theme-install-frame-params`</kbd>

> `(color-theme-install-frame-params PARAMS)`
>
> Change frame parameters using alist `PARAMETERS`.
>
> If `color-theme-is-global` is non-nil, all frames are modified using `modify-frame-parameters` and the `PARAMETERS` are prepended to `default-frame-alist`. The value of `initial-frame-alist` is not modified.  If `color-theme-is-global` is nil, only the selected frame is modified. If `color-theme-is-cumulative` is nil, the frame parameters are restored from `color-theme-original-frame-alist`.
>
> If the current frame parameters have a parameter `minibuffer` with value `only`, then the frame parameters are not installed, since this indicates a dedicated minibuffer frame.

Answer (score 3):

Position your cursor ("[point](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Point.html)" in GNU Emacs parlance) where you want to set the "background". Preferably where there is no text displayed. Then enter `M-x describe-face`.

Emacs will tell you witch [face](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html) (all that GNU Emacs can display have a "face") you are looking at. Most probably "default". Then in the bottom of the window, click on "you can customize this face".

You are now "in [customize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html)". (it is just some sort of wizard to get/set values from/to your [~/.emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)) Set the background color you want, then click on "save for future sessions".

There you have it. Now look at the bottom of your ~/.emacs, inside `(custom-set-faces ...)`, this is your face definition.

**BTW**, color-theme is now somehow [built-in GNU Emacs 24](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472367/539797). I have this in my .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables

...stuff...

 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))

...stuff...)
```

Comment: In this case, it turns out you need to do the following: `(custom-set-faces \`(default ((t (:background "gray13")))))`